# String/Sequence Pattern Mining

Tags: java, string, sequence

it's a week i'm trying to find an answer for my question , i would appreciate if anyone can help .
I've got a list of strings(originally list of sequences which can be viewed as list of strings) and i'd like to find a pattern (which is a string itself) withtin strings of this list , is there any java library which can i use or is there any tool (like weka , which doesn't do this!) which can help me ??

Comment: Do you want an exact match or an approximate one?

Comment: & i should already note that we don't have any predefined pattern , i want to detect a pattern which is recurring in the list

Comment: what do u mean of exact or approximate ?

Comment: an example : input : ABCDEFG , ACDF , ACFG ---> result : ACF

Comment: Ah, that seems to be the LCS problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: @Aryan_wk: please update your question instead of adding more info in comments.

Comment: Sorry , new to this forum , thanks for your helps

Comment: i found LCS is only for two files , i've many (probably more than 100000) strings to find a pattern within

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to find the [longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) of those strings. This is a well known algorithmic problem that is commonly solved using dynamic programming. See [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Longest_common_subsequence) for various implementations in multiple languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find patterns frequently occuring in a set of sequence, then you could try "sequential pattern mining" or "sequential rule mining algorithms".

There are several implementations of these algorithms in my [SPMF Java open-source data mining library](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/).